# How do you call and SSIS Package via and SSMS Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

I feel like this should be easy but I have scoured the internet and I can't find a good point of reference on where to start.

I have an SSIS Package that I use to copy a bunch of tables from our AS400 into my SQL Server Data Warehouse. Then I run some stored procedure to generate data for a number of reports. I currently trigger this manually. 
I want to be able to trigger this SSIS Script via a Stored Procedure. The package I want is stored in Integration Services, not on a local machine. It is the same server that SSMS lives on.

I feel like this should be easy, and fairly common but I can't seem to figure it out. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Image: My SSIS IDE
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Almost all actions in SSMS can generate a script by clicking the `Script` button that appears in almost all dialog boxes. To generate the execution script, right click on the package you want to execute and click on the `Script` button on the top left.

This generates a script like this:

```
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'MyPackageName.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, @folder_name=N'MyFolder', @project_name=N'MyProject', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=1
Select @execution_id
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
```

GO

Comment: Hmm, yeah I did see someone else mention that in another thread i was reading, but I don't see the option anywhere. I'm using Sequel Server 2008 R2...

Comment: The option is available since 2008 at least

Comment: Ok cool, is there any way you could send me a screenshot/pic of what i'm looking for i've never used this option and I don't see it anywhere.  Thanks again.

Comment: Better yet i added a pic of my SSMS/SSIS to show you what I'm seeing.